# Asynchronous Tasks take too much time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have been trying make an asynchronous approach to my CPU-bound function which compute some aggregate functions. The thing is that there is some Deadlock (I suppose), because the time of calculation is too different. I am reallz newbie in this Task Parallel world, I also read Stephem Cleary articles but I am still unsure of all aspect this asynchronous approach.
My Code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PIServer server = ConnectToDefaultPIServer();
    AFTimeRange timeRange = new AFTimeRange("1/1/2012", "6/30/2012");
    Program p = new Program();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        p.TestAsynchronousCall(server, timeRange);
        //p.TestAsynchronousCall(server, timeRange).Wait();-same results
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Main check-disconnected done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private async Task TestAsynchronousCall(PIServer server, AFTimeRange timeRange)
{
    AsyncClass asyn;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        asyn = new AsyncClass();
        await asyn.DoAsyncTask(server, timeRange);
        //asyn.DoAsyncTask(server, timeRange);-same results
    }
}

public async Task DoAsyncTask(PIServer server, AFTimeRange timeRange)
{
        var timeRanges = DivideTheTimeRange(timeRange);
        Task<Dictionary<PIPoint, AFValues>>[] tasksArray = new Task<Dictionary<PIPoint, AFValues>>[2];

        tasksArray[0] = (Task.Run(() => CalculationClass.AverageValueOfTagPerDay(server, timeRanges[0])));
        // tasksArray[1] = tasksArray[0].ContinueWith((x) => CalculationClass.AverageValueOfTagPerDay(server, timeRanges[1]));
        tasksArray[1] = (Task.Run(() => CalculationClass.AverageValueOfTagPerDay(server, timeRanges[1])));


        Task.WaitAll(tasksArray);
        //await Task.WhenAll(tasksArray); -same results
        for (int i = 0; i < tasksArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Program.Show(tasksArray[i].Result);
        }
}
```

I measure time throught Stopwatch in AverageValueOfTagPerDay functions. This function is synchronous (Is that a problem?). Each Task take 12 seconds. But when I uncommented the line and use ContinueWith() approach, these Tasks take 5-6 seconds each(which is desirable). How is it possible?

More strange is that when I set the for loop in Main() on 10, sometimes it takes 5 seconds as well as when I use ContinueWith(). So I guess somewhere is deadlock but I am unable to find that.

Sorry for english, I got still problem make good senteces when I try explain some difficulties.

Comment: you do realise that your first for next is going to execute each iteration sequentially. Why not use forparallel ?

Comment: DoAsyncTask is incomplete : `try` without `catch` nor `finally`. It's marked as `async` but doesn't use `await`. You have multiple tasks using the same instance of `PIServer`, is this class thread safe ?

Comment: so it doesn't even compile. AsyncTask does not have to be async.

Comment: Phillip Stuyck: That for loop in Main and TestAsynchronousCall is only for testing purpose-I need to compare compute time for each call. Also that try catch is only because i forget to remove it. DoAsyncTask have to be async because after i Run 2 Tasks i have to wait for the results which are input to Program.Show() method.

Comment: Guillaume: About the DoAsyncTask when I remove keyword async and change return type to void I got the same time compute results. But thanks for advice I didn't realize that. This method was async because I have tried use a keyword await (commented line). Good point about that PiServer, I will check it out!

Answer (score 5):

> I have been trying make an asynchronous approach to my CPU-bound function which compute some aggregate functions.

"Asynchronous" and "CPU-bound" are not terms that go together. If you have a CPU-bound process, then you should use parallel technologies (`Parallel`, Parallel LINQ, TPL Dataflow).

> I am reallz newbie in this Task Parallel world, I also read Stephem Cleary articles but I am still unsure of all aspect this asynchronous approach.

Possibly because I do not cover parallel technologies in any of my articles or blog posts. :)  I do cover them in my book, but not online. My online work focuses on asynchrony, which is ideal for I/O-based operations.

To solve your problem, you should use a parallel approach:

```
public Dictionary<PIPoint, AFValues>[] DoTask(PIServer server, AFTimeRange timeRange)
{
  var timeRanges = DivideTheTimeRange(timeRange);
  var result = timeRanges.AsParallel().AsOrdered().
      Select(range => CalculationClass.AverageValueOfTagPerDay(server, range)).
      ToArray();
  return result;
}
```

Of course, this approach assumes that `PIServer` is threadsafe. It also assumes that there's no I/O being done by the "server" class; if there is, then TPL Dataflow may be a better choice than Parallel LINQ.

If you are planning to use this code in a UI application and don't want to block the UI thread, then you can *call* the code asynchronously like this:

```
var results = await Task.Run(() => DoTask(server, timeRange));
foreach (var result in results)
  Program.Show(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I always though that Asynchronous approach is not good for CPU-bound operations but when I have read you [article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) you wrote: _So, the question remains: Where should I use Task.Run?Use Task.Run to call CPU-bound methods. That is all._ I also have been reading your book because I am really exciting about that. And I meant to refer to Task Parallel Library which is using Task. So I am still a bit confused about correct names. I believe that PiServer is thread safe, I will try it and I will let you know

Comment: Well I tried that AsParallel() and I got the exact same result(12 seconds for each) and my goal is that this compute is under 6 seconds. So I gonna look at TPL Dataflow. Also I should mentioned that this is a pure console application and that aggregation function which compute average for each day is compure on the server side (which in this case is my local server).So I suppose it is satisfies I/O approach. I mean output from server is the concrete averages. BTW Thanks a lot for response :-)

Comment: @Alexander_Dracka: If I understand you correctly, then the operation *for this process* is I/O-bound, not CPU-bound. And in that case you'd probably want to use `async` with `Task.WhenAll`. One thing to check (if your server is ASP.NET) is that the server request has session state disabled.